# Access to Mongoid 3 master node

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongoid

How do you get access to the master node in Mongoid > 3.0 ?

In Mongoid < 3.0 you could use:

```
Mongoid::Config.master.eval('...')
```

The closest I can find in 3 seems to be:

```
klass.collection.database.command(eval: '...') #=> failed with error "not master"
```

Is there a better way to get access to master? Or a way to ensure the command is evaluated by the master node?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mongoid 3.0 uses Moped and not the 10gen driver, so see Moped::Cluster#with_primary

http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/master/Moped/Cluster:with_primary

For example:

```
User.collection.database.session.cluster.with_primary do
  p User.collection.database.command(eval: 'function() { return 3+3; }')
  p User.collection.database.command(ping: 1)
end
```

output:

```
{"retval"=>6.0, "ok"=>1.0}
{"ok"=>1.0}
```

Note that other possible solutions like group, aggregation, and mapreduce are recommended over eval.

Comment: Thank you. I desperately needed to run a repair, a lá "Mongoid.master.command({'repairDatabase' => 1})" but could not anymore in mongoid 3. Instead I did something like "SomeModel.collection.database.command({'repairDatabase' => 1})"

Comment: What about using `SomeModel.mongo_session`?

Comment: it seems the block `User.collection.database.session.cluster.with_primary do` is not necessary